# Difference Between Windows Update and Windows 10 Update Assistant

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I was trying to download the Windows 10 Fall Creator's Update, and it came to my attention that it requires the Windows 10 Update Assistant, which I know comes with Windows 10, but that I most likely deleted (lol.)

My question is, in the Windows Settings App, under Update and Security, my computer is up to date:

[image]

However, on the Windows 10 Update Assistant, I had a ton of updates available:

[image]

From a logical standpoint, why would Microsoft not integrate the Windows 10 Updates into the settings application or vice versa; getting rid of the Update section of the setting application and having us use the Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant?

It's very likely that I'm overthinking this, or that I'm missing something blatantly obvious, but I would appreciate any suggestions/guidance.

Comment: The newest build of Windows has not been confirmed compatible with all hardware combinations.  Microsoft is effectively making a multi-month public QA process by having early adopters intentionally download the new Fall Creator's Update, and expose problems before releasing it to everyone else.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage, interesting, because I didn't intentionally download the new Creator's Update and I've never used the Upgrade Assistant.  After the install I had a shortcut to the Upgrade Assistant on my desktop.

Comment: Oh, so it's like a beta program in some sorts then? @ChristopherHostage

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths If your computer is confirmed stable by Microsoft, they may roll out the changes automatically. My PC is custom built so compatibility is questionable

Comment: Precisely.  Backup everything important before going to the new build.  It has a reasonably reliable rollback mechanism, but back up anyway.

Comment: My PC is custom-built as well. The Anniversary update (1508 I think) was delayed on my computer, and I used the Upgrade Assistant to get it when I wanted it. Both Creators Updates (1703 and now 1709) have been made available to my computer on day one.

Comment: @music2myear - Anniversary is 1607 not 1508.  1508 isn't even a valid version number for Windows 10.  1507 is Windows 10 RTM, 1511 is the November Update, 1703 and 1709 are CU and (Fall) CU respectfully.  [Windows 10 version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history)

Comment: Yea, that's why I said "I think".

Comment: Let me add, then, that my rig is custom but I did just do a fresh re-install on it.  Maybe that's why it was deemed good to go day one.  In any case, I didn't even know what the Upgrade Assistant was, I just always went into settings and checked for updates.

Comment: @music2myear - knowledge is power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1709 showed on my computer Tuesday evening and installed just fine using the standard Microsoft Update mechanism.

To ease load and to minimize issues, Microsoft does stagger the availability of their major releases. Using the Upgrade Assistant will generally circumvent this staggering and will get you the latest major version right away.

Comment: It's strange, because before using the Upgrade Assistant I was still on 1703, which seems VERY far behind

Comment: Uh, no. 1703 (literally, 2017-March) was the last major update. 1709 (2017-September) is the current major update. You're confusing patches and major versions, perhaps? The numbers are not supposed to be single-increment-consecutive either. The next major update will be 1803, and the one after that will be 1809.

Comment: I thought at some point Windows rolled out a major *update* to fix Defender issues? Perhaps I'm confused and it was a patch.

Comment: Would a fix to a single small part of the OS count as a major version or a patch? Updates may individually be important, or "major", but when we're talking about Windows 10 "Major Updates" we are referring to the biannual version updates, sometimes called "editions" as well. The Upgrade Assistant deals only with these version changes.

Comment: Alright, that actually makes a ton of sense! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @David - You do understand, that 1703 was the current version on Monday, correct?

Comment: @Ramhound If you read the convo, you can see that yes. I do. No need to ask

Answer (score -3):

If an update doesn't show up in settings' update page , then it means that the update wouldn't be perfect as supposed to be on your system with some bugs while running. So ,it is better to wait until the update is available on your settings' update page.